# Securing Webhooks for Jira and MS Teams integration

Tags: webhooks

We implemented sending Webhooks from Jira Data Center to MS Teams, one-way communication. 
[Atlassian document](https://success.atlassian.com/solution-resources/work-management/wm-topics/integration-with-microsoft-teams)

But for security it is not viable solution as not any authentication takes place. After reading all the materials we can't find any option to add security for to avoid attack MS teams end point from unknown webhook sources.
Can you advise please if and what could be the options to add security?

/Tarmo

There seems to be no measure to authenticate Incoming Webhook while integration Jira and Teams

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.